# How does the planet Starkiller base in the Force Awakens remain day light once the weapon is charged?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

How many suns are around Starkiller base in the Force Awakens? Is it just one? If its sucks the power out of one star from the back of the planet how is the front of the planet lit up like the sun is shinning on it when the Rebels attack it? If the weapon is charged shouldn't the plant be in the dark?

Comment: Although not mentioned, I believe the idea is that the Starkiller can travel through space like the Death Star, in search of stars.

Comment: @MrLister to kill them...

Comment: Seems duplicate, seveal questions address this. Short version - this is an idiotic blooper in the film/script by Abrams that doesn't make sense; and novelization fixed it to a much more sensible point that they use the Sun's ENERGY, not the whole sun

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/111712/how-is-the-starkiller-base-supposed-to-work-more-than-one-time-given-how-it-dra/111715#111715

Comment: @JackBNimble I can see the Imperial Recruiting posters now: "Transfer to Starkiller base, travel the galaxy, meet interesting star systems, and blow them up"

Comment: @Richard It is true that the Empire likes to give things misleading names. Star Destroyers, DeathStars, StarKillers. Although certainly in the film my impression was that star really was killed.

Answer (score 3):

The Starkiller Base system (initally) has a single star. This is confirmed in the film's [Official Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens_(novel)).

> *Given the chance, she would have remained in the medbay, where the
>   Wookiee set his burden down. But despite its added modifications, the
>   Falcon still flew better with someone in the copilot’s seat. In
>   moments they were beyond the atmosphere of the imploding planet. The
>   jump to lightspeed was accomplished without incident, preventing them
>   from observing the final cataclysm. Which was just as well. **A moment after they fled, Starkiller Base system became a binary.***

As to how they're able to fire a ***second shot***, I suggest you have a read of this question/answer set

- [How is the Starkiller Base supposed to work more than one time, given how it draws its power?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/111712/how-is-the-starkiller-base-supposed-to-work-more-than-one-time-given-how-it-dra/111715#111715)