# Did Starkiller base have a hyperdrive? If so, what class?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

It has been mentioned that the first Death Star had a class 4 Hyperdrive and a class 20 backup, so it could move from system to system (so it could destroy targets.) As the weapons system of the First Order's Starkiller base is partly based off of the Death Star weapons system, **does Starkiller base have a hyperdrive to move?**

Comment: It would seem necessary to find another star if you wanted to fire it more than once?

Comment: @DavidW What's the need of firing more than once if there was no target left after first firing?

Answer (score 1):

## No, it was made stationary

Starkiller was built stationary on a planet. Also, it used hyperspace to target systems very far away, thus eliminating the need to move in order to fire. It is never mentioned that the station was moved from one location to another, but secretly built on a remote planet in unknown areas of the Galaxy.

The planet-station is mentioned as 'mobile', but only rocket ports are used for that. It is unlikely that such technology could be effectively used to move the planet across the galaxy, but rather for orbit correction and rotation (as in real life space stations), so that the firing side can be properly adjusted.

<sub>From **Star Wars: Force Awakening official novelization eBook by Alan Dean Foster, Chapter X** (emphasis mine)</sub>

> The fleet of Star Destroyers stood off the white world. Spectacular and isolated, with a mean surface
>   temperature varying from merely cold to permanently arctic, **the planet had been altered**: its mountains
>   tunneled into, its glaciers hacked, and its valleys modified until it no longer resembled its original
>   naturally eroded form. Those who had remade it had renamed it.
>
> **Starkiller Base.**

Chapter XIV
Finn:

> “General Hux told us it’s the most powerful weapon ever built. He said that it can reach
>   halfway across the galaxy.” Fresh murmurs of disbelief greeted this latest assertion. “And in real time.
>   Because it doesn’t reach across the galaxy; it reaches through it.”

From Wookieepedia article on [Starkiller base](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Starkiller_Base): (emphasis mine)

> Starkiller Base was a mobile ice planet located in the Unknown Regions that served as a stronghold of the First Order thirty years after the Battle of Endor. Commanded by an unofficial triumvirate of General Armitage Hux, Kylo Ren and Captain Phasma, it was armed with a superweapon capable of destroying entire star systems halfway across the galaxy. The First Order viewed this ability as an evolution of the planet-destroying capabilities of the Galactic Empire's Death Star designs, with the weapon serving as the ultimate culmination of Old Empire research into dark energy translations and **hyperspace tunneling**.

[10 Facts on The Force Awakens - Empire Magazine](https://www.empireonline.com/movies/features/star-wars-force-awakens-dvd-10-things-learned/), <sub>quoted in the article above</sub>

> Fun facts that aren't revealed in the film: 1) the First Order chose this planet because of its minerals, and 2) yes, it can move, since it has **rocket ports** on its far side

Comment: Interesting - do you have a source / quote on it using hyperspace to target distant systems? I wasn't aware that was possible.

Comment: The whole idea of the Starkiller base was to draw energy from a star and target it via hyperspace to a remote system. Will find a supporting quote from the same book.

Comment: Note that the Wookiepedia article says it's a "**mobile** ice planet," and the footnote suggests that there's a source for that.

Comment: @DavidW the source is unofficial and mentions "rocket ports". I think these are mainly for orbit correction and rotation, so that the fire can be directed, but not for long range space travel.

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/111715/20774 - It's mobile

Comment: I am finding it hard to accept this answer, when in fact @Valorum has just detailed a contradiction

Comment: At the very least, nothing in the quotes presented here *preclude* the ability to move the entire base through hyperspace, only that the base doesn't *need* to do so (assuming it doesn't entirely consume the local star).

Answer (score 0):

It has to have a hyperdrive or it would take years to reload a shot, if each firing of it's main weapon can destroy multiple planets and requires a whole star to be consumed for fuel, then it would need hyperspace travelling capabilities to have moved to another star. In The Force Awakens, the First Order fire an initial volley of the main weapon at the Hosnian System, this presumably used up the star they were fuelling Starkiller Base with at the start of the movie. They're going to need to move several light years to get close to another star in order for it's next shot at the Rebel Base on D'Qar to have the energy it needs.

Though during the final charging sequence at the end of TFA, we do see the sky go dark, while there is sunlight visible during the firing sequence that targeted the New Republic. The system it's located in may be a binary star system as we have seen with Tatooine and multiple real world examples. But I doubt the First Order spent decades and huge amounts of resources to refit an entire planet into a superweapon in order to just use it twice, it would have to have a hyperdrive, even a very slow one, in order to be a worthwhile investment, the only other alternative is even more absurd, which is that they somehow can move entire stars through hyperspace towards Starkiller Base, and if they had that technology, why not just use it to move the Hosnian System's Star into the New Republic planets?

Comment: do you have any canon evidenciary source for this answer, espcially considering that the question linked in this comment seems to have an official confirmation that it is indeed mobile? https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/111712/how-is-the-starkiller-base-supposed-to-work-more-than-one-time-given-how-it-dra/